# Ratio of two CDFs (t-distribution)

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, t-distribution

Is there an expression for the ratio of two Student's t CDFs with different degrees of freedom: $\frac{T_{\nu-k}(x)}{T_{\nu}(x)}$?

Comment: Sure, because you can plug in expressions for the two CDFs separately.  What, then, are you looking for beyond that?  Indeed, could you explain the statistical meaning of this ratio?  I ask this because it's possible you really want the CDF of the ratio of random variables following these two distributions instead of the ratio of the CDFs.

Comment: I'm simplifying an expression and this fraction appears there. Thus, I'm wondering if I can simply it further.

Comment: Probably not. ...